# How to fire POST request using inline editor in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, fulfillment

**Code:**

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var options = {
                method: 'POST',
                uri: 'http://c663fe13.ngrok.io/ap/lighton',
                body: {"color": 'white'},
                json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
            };

            rp(options)
                .then(function (parsedBody) {
                    // POST succeeded...+
                    console.log("parsedBody", parsedBody);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    // POST failed...
                    console.log("err", err);
                });
```

but this gives me the following error:

> { RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN c663fe13.ngrok.io:80
>       at new RequestError (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
>       at Request.plumbing.callback (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
>       at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
>
> .  .  .
>
> name: 'RequestError',   message: 'Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
>   c663fe13.ngrok.io:80',
>    cause:     { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
>   c663fe13.ngrok.io:80
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
>        errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
>        code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
>        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>        hostname: 'c663fe13.ngrok.io',
>        host: 'c663fe13.ngrok.io',
>        port: 80 },

I trie to call that API with postman and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a free account you will not be able to hit any 3rd party services from Firebase cloud functions. It would be better if you write down your own webhook code and using fulfillment integrate that webhook with your Dialogflow agent if you are going to use the free account.

**UPDATE**
Check out the code snippets I have shared [here](https://gist.github.com/abhi007tyagi/1b0a5d775fc2af7aae89b8c20d33a397). You can use that to integrate ExpressJS and then add your POST code and host it locally. Expose the local server using ngrok and then put that URL in fulfillment.

Comment: Okay, and for the solution, do you have any example on that?

Comment: should I use all 3 things or just Express JS with Dialogflow is enough?

Comment: Depends on your use. If using Action on Google you will need the second one.
If you are new to NodeJS then please go through some online tutorials first for better understanding.

Comment: Yes, I am using Action on Google. I tried inline fulfillment but as you know It can't be done because of a free account. thanks for the node suggestion but I have done node very well bro.  just confusing with dialogflow and action-on-google.

Comment: then just use the code snippet and enjoy Google Assistant ;)

Comment: Sure, I'll try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am not able to use server tunneled by ngrok because it was running on HTTP and while adding that URL to Fulfillment it show **You can use the only https:// in fulfillment URL when "Google Assistant" integration enabled**

Comment: ngrok gives https option. I am using it